# Magento 1.9. Sales rules with quantity in cart not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, rules

Magento sales rules with the next configuration (
  Quantity in cart equals or greater than 1 
  AND Quantity in cart equals or less than 4) 
not working, it's applyng for product even there are 7 products in shopping cart:

[image: Sales rule configuration]
[image: Frontend]
it is a clean magento 1.9.2.3. Probłem with compare "1", if I create Quantity in cart equals or greater than 2 AND Quantity in cart equals or less than 4. Than it works fine

Comment: On clean Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 your cart rule works fine.

Comment: I'm using clean magento 1.9.2.3 with Demo data

Comment: On clean magento 1.9.2.4 your cart rule works fine too.

Comment: It's possible that you have another rule that has Action "Stop Further Rules Processing" set to "Yes". If by any reason this rule is valid then all rest rules that are suppose to be validated would not be processed.